# Kendo UI Angular Grid Detail template "+" icon to be moved to last column

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

[+ icon to be moved to right far end]

Iam using kendo angular Grid, where i need to customize the "+" icon to be the last column of the grid. by default it comes as the first column. can anybody help on acheiving it.

Comment: Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432466/kendo-ui-for-angular-grid-detail-expand-collapse-button-to-be-moved-to-the-right?rq=1), it is the same as what you are trying to do.

Comment: ive trie but it dosesnt hide the entire column, it just hides the content. MarissaFernandes

Comment: Could you please share some code like which CSS classes to hide the column, the grid markup and also a screenshot of what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:-

- Hide the detail icon column. I found this [telerik forum link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-the-expand-collapse-column-of-a-detail-grid-9eaa98b16b92) which explains how to hide the expand and collapse detail grid column.
- Add a new column for the detail icon to be displayed on the right.
- Call collapseRow and expandRow grid methods respectively onclick of the detail icon.
- Handle detailCollapse and detailExpand grid events respectively to toggle the detail icon for expand and collapse

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to hide the column itself in the callback function.

```
rowCallback({ dataItem, index }) {
    $('.k-hierarchy-col').css('width', '0px');
    $('td.k-hierarchy-cell').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('th.k-hierarchy-cell').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you must change navigatable in details grid to false
(kendoGridDetailTemplate)

```
<kendo-grid [navigatable]="false">
</kendo-grid>
```